# Using setUp defined variables in parametrized.expand

Tags: python, unit-testing

Suppose that I have the following unit test class:

```
class Test(unittest.TestCase)
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.test_parameter1 = 'A'
        self.test_parameter2 = 'B'
    
    @parametrized.expand([('A',), ('B',)])
    def test_function1(self, test_param):
        * Do tests here *
```

Is there a way how can I use `self.test_parameter1` and `self.test_parameter2` in `parameterized.expand` instead of the literals `A` and `B`? Imagine `A` and `B` are large dicts, the tests would be very messy in this case if two large dicts are given to `parametrized_expand`.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverlow ! Afaik this is not possible => tests are expanded before testclasses are initiated... maybe if your self_test_paramter1 is a callable ... but thats something to be tried I'll follow your question

Answer (score 0):

Yes - `test_function` is a method on your `Test` class so in your `test_function` you just need to use `self.test_parameter1` & `self.test_parameter2` where you would use A & B.

For example:

```
    @parametrized_expand([('A',), ('B',)])
    def test_function1(self, test_param):
       self.assertEqual(test.parameter1 + self.test_paramter2, 10)
```

Comment: What I meant is using `self.test_parameter1` and `self.test_parameter2` instead of 'A' and 'B' inside the `parameterized.expand` decorator

Comment: @DylanGalea - no - because of when the decorator is executed, those attributes don't exist. The best you could do is pass the names of the parameters, and then use `getattr` to fetch the attributes.

But if you are storing them as attributes, then why do you need them as paramterised too ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can set them up to be references outside of the test class (they'll be executed on import by unittest) and expand (`*`) or un`zip` 'em in the decorator args

```py
test_parameter1 = dict_A
test_parameter2 = dict_B

expanded_args = list(zip(test_parameter1.items(), test_parameter2.items()))

class Test(unittest.TestCase)
    @parametrized.expand(expanded_args)
    def test_function1(self, test_param):
        * Do tests here *
```

Comment: This could be a good option. But I was looking for a way such that the parameters are then re-declared by setUp, just in case no other test messes up with the variables declared outside the class.

Comment: Perhaps you could call `.copy()` on 'em before passing to `.expand()`?

Comment: Another option I found was to pass the variable name is `parametrized.expand` and then use `eval`.

Comment: @DylanGalea could you please give an example how you used eval within your expand? I struggle with the same problem.